# How to know if admob are not coming in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, admob

I am using admobs and i want to know if admobs are not coming.
If admobs are not coming then i should hide that view and when they start coming again then i have to show them onscren.
if my question is silly then don't mind please.
any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use delegate functions to know whether ads are getting received or not and then handle it accordingly.

Use GADBannerViewDelegate

Implement delegate functions like this:

```
// We've received an ad successfully.

- (void)adViewDidReceiveAd:(GADBannerView *)adView {
    NSLog(@"Received ad successfully");
}

// Ad Not Recieved

- (void)adView:(GADBannerView *)view
didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(GADRequestError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Failed to receive ad with error: %@", [error localizedFailureReason]);
}

- (void)adViewWillPresentScreen:(GADBannerView *)bannerView
{
    NSLog(@"will Present");
}
```